# Some issues in upgrading to bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, mean-stack, web-frontend

I'm a Full Stack Developer, but I am new to bootstrap and I upgraded a bootstrap 3 theme to bootstrap 5.
But the theme have some changes, at first I thought that the font size, after that I looked for elements sizing, searching in a lot of topics, until I found that the theme becomes unresponsive, work as a smartphone browser with all devices.
Please help me fixing this issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you follow the advice in the migration guides? [v3 to v4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/migration/#summary) and [v4 to v5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/)

Comment: Yes, I did. and i'm reading the both guides again to know where the problem.